# Getting segmentation error while copying mp4 file to shared memory using memcpy()

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I am writing a code to share data using shared memory, for txt data my code is working but for mp4 files it is not working sender is not able to send data.

EDIT: after changing buffer size as suggested segmentation error at sender side got resolved but getting the **same segmentation issue in receiver side.**

```
// receiver Side
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    void *shared_memory;
    char buffer[4];
    int shm_id;
    char *shared_buffer;

    // Get the shared memory segment (key, size, flags)
    shm_id = shmget((key_t)1122, 1024, 0666);
    if (shm_id == -1) {
        cerr << "shmget failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Attach the process to the shared memory segment
    shared_memory = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) {
        cerr << "shmat failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // shared_buffer is pointer to shared_memory
    shared_buffer = static_cast<char *>(shared_memory);

    // calculating size of sample.txt
    ifstream inputFile("sample.mp4", ios::binary); // Corrected the filename

    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening sample.txt" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int total_bytes = 0;
    inputFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
    streamsize total_byte = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    inputFile.close();

    total_bytes = (int) total_byte;

    cout << " >> " << total_bytes << endl;
    // end of calculate size 
    struct shmid_ds buf;
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_STAT, &buf);
    int length = (int) buf.shm_segsz;

    cout << "Key of shared memory: " << shm_id << endl;
    cout << "LENGTH shared memory at: " << length << endl;

    ofstream outputFile("received.mp4", ios::binary);
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        memcpy(buffer, shared_buffer, min((int)sizeof(buffer),total_bytes));
        //cout << i++ << " :: > " << buffer << endl;
        
       // Check for a signal indicating the end of data
        /*
        if (strncmp(buffer, "END_DATA!!!", 11) == 0) {
            //outputFile.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            cout << "Received END_DATA signal. Exiting the loop." << endl;
            break;
        }
        */
        
        cout << " :: >> :" << min((int)sizeof(buffer),total_bytes) << endl;
        shared_buffer += sizeof(buffer);
        outputFile.write(buffer, min((int)sizeof(buffer),total_bytes));
        
        if (total_bytes <= 0){
            break;
        }
        total_bytes -= min((int)sizeof(buffer),total_bytes);
        
    }

    cout << "Data from shared memory written to received.txt" << endl;
    outputFile.close();
    // Detach the shared memory segment
    shmdt(shared_memory);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Sender Side 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    void *shared_memory;
    //char buffer[1024];
    int shm_id;
    char *shared_buffer; 
    
    // Get the shared memory segment (key, size, flags)
    shm_id = shmget((key_t)1122, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (shm_id == -1) {
        cerr << "shmget failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Attach the process to the shared memory segment
    shared_memory = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) {
        cerr << "shmat failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // shared_buffer is pointer to shared_memory
    shared_buffer = static_cast<char *>(shared_memory);

    cout << "Key of shared memory: " << shm_id << endl;
    cout << "Process attached to shared memory at: " << shared_memory << endl;

    ifstream inputFile("sample.mp4", ios::binary); // Corrected the filename

    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening sample.txt" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 0;

    int total_bytes = 0;
    inputFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
    streamsize fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);

    cout << "Total Bytes :==>> " << total_bytes << endl;
    char *buffer = new char[1024];

    cout <<  " :: " << fileSize << endl;
    total_bytes = (int) fileSize;
    while (true) {
        inputFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        int bytes_read = inputFile.gcount();
        if (total_bytes <= 0){
            break;
        }
        // Copy the read data into shared memory
        memcpy(shared_buffer, buffer, bytes_read);
        total_bytes -= bytes_read;
        shared_buffer += bytes_read;
        //cout << "total bytes" << " >> " << bytes_read << " << " << buffer << endl;
    }
    
    inputFile.close();
    cout << "Data from sample.txt is shared in shared memory" << endl;

    // Detach the shared memory segment
    shmdt(shared_memory);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried adding "End_of_file" so that sender loop can terminate. but it seems it is    terminating before sending the complete file.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is very likely equal to `8` (or `4` if you're on a 32-bit system). Don't use pointers and dynamic allocation for a simple array like `buffer`.

Comment: I also recommend you change your reading loop to `while (inputFile.read(...))`.